# Play externally hosted videos on drupal site

Tags: url, video, drupal-7, preview

I am using [statuses module 7.x-1.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) and [opengraph filter 7.x-1.0-beta1](https://www.drupal.org/project/opengraph_filter) to generate preview from url in status updates. It is doing it successfully, however, I have tried a lot, but I am unable to play those videos on site. When I click it, it takes me to the link. For example when someone shares a youtube or fb video link or etc.

How can I play these videos on my site without hosting it on my site?

Secondly, the thumbnail it is generating is very small.

Comment: Depends on how you are trying to make this work. Do you have a video field and you want it to turn into a player? If that is the case you can create a template for the content type and wrap the url in the corresponding video tags. If this is not the case, you can also use jquery to find video links and wrap them in the embed codes. I would say do it in the theme before you do it with jquery.

Comment: Thank you. I want to convert it into a player. When someone clicks the thumbnail, it must play the video on site. Best if in an overlay. I cannot code, so please give a solution, if you can, in an easy to understand and implement. Sure with proper guide/tutorial I can implement custom code, if required

Comment: I am not using video module. Please keep in mind that I want to implement this in status updates provided by "statuses module".

Comment: Do you have a specific field where they enter the url of the video? Or are the videos randomly placed in long text?

Comment: No specific field. Just put the link in status update box while writing a status update. With other text, smileys, mentions, hashtags etc etc. Like when we are tweeting we share a link with our tweet.

Comment: If you know about facebook style micro publisher sub-module for statuses, it has option for sharing link, photo, video and documents with status updates, but I am not using it. As these things will be hosted on my site if I do.

Comment: I installed video filter module and enable it in text formats. Now I see embeded videos, but there are few problems.
1. user must use [video:URL] this format when sharing links

Comment: 2. Conflicting with open graph filter, however, working fine, but giving this error Notice: Undefined index: request_uri in template_preprocess_opengraph_filter() (line 377 of C:\Users\xyz\Sites\devdesktop\project_kickstart\profiles\project_kickstart\modules\contrib\opengraph_filter\opengraph_filter.module)